# Print this format using Java

Tags: java, arrays

i can able to print as below format using java

Output:

```
    1 2 3 
    4 5 6 
    7 8 9
```

Java:

```
int a = 1;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){ 
 for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
   System.out.print(a++);
 } 
 System.out.println("");
}
```

But I need this Output as below?

```
1   8  15
2   9  16
3  10
4  11
5  12
6  13
7  14
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Calendar format

Comment: What java code you have written for the above output ?

Comment: its for this Output:

    1 2 3 
    4 5 6 
    7 8 9         Similarly i need for calendar output as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if statements inside for loop: Below is a working sample:

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){ 
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        if(j == 0) {
            System.out.print(i+1+" ");  
        }
        if(j == 1) {
            System.out.print(i+1+7+ " ");   
        }
        if(j == 2 && i < 2) {
            System.out.print(i+1+14);   
        }
    } 
    System.out.println("");
}
```